# QGraphicsView scale scene gives weird results

Tags: python, qt5, pyside2, qgraphicsview

Inside the `QGraphView`'s `mouseMoveEvent` I'm calculating the difference of the mouse position to scale the view's scene by scaling a transform. This seems to work well, but it scales in a weird way. Like it almost feels like it makes the items slide as the anchor to which it scales from doesn't feel fixed. I'm including a gif since that should help explain what I'm talking about. I tried fooling around with the anchor settings and they seem to do nothing at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class QGraphView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QGraphView, self).__init__(parent)

        self._scene_rect = None
        self._scene_transform = None
        self._start_point = None

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(self.NoAnchor)
        self.setResizeAnchor(self.NoAnchor)

        graph_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(graph_scene)

        graph_scene.addEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100, brush=QtGui.QColor("red"), pen=QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        graph_scene.addEllipse(400, 0, 100, 100, brush=QtGui.QColor("red"), pen=QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self._scene_rect = self.sceneRect()
        self._scene_transform = self.viewportTransform()
        self._start_point = event.pos()

        super(QGraphView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(QGraphView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self._start_point = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ALT:
            # Translates scene with mouse.
            deltas = self._start_point - event.pos()

            self.setSceneRect(
                self._scene_rect.x() + deltas.x(),
                self._scene_rect.y() + deltas.y(),
                self._scene_rect.width(), self._scene_rect.height())
        elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ALT:
            # Scales scene. FEELS BROKEN!
            deltas = event.pos() - self._start_point
            scalar = deltas.x() * 0.005

            transform = QtGui.QTransform(self._scene_transform)
            transform.scale(1 + scalar, 1 + scalar)

            self.setTransform(transform)
        else:
            super(QGraphView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
```

[image: Example of bad scaling]

**Update:**

I tweaked the events a bit and scale seems to be doing what I expect, but for some reason translate sticks and pops when it is zoomed in. It seems simple enough to calculate so I'm not exactly sure why that's happening:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class QGraphView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QGraphView, self).__init__(parent)

        self._scene_rect = None
        self._scene_transform = None
        self._start_point = None

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(self.NoAnchor)
        self.setResizeAnchor(self.NoAnchor)

        graph_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(graph_scene)

        graph_scene.addEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100, brush=QtGui.QColor("red"), pen=QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        graph_scene.addEllipse(400, 0, 100, 100, brush=QtGui.QColor("red"), pen=QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(QGraphView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        self._scene_rect = self.sceneRect()
        self._scene_transform = self.viewportTransform()
        self._start_point = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(QGraphView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self._scene_rect = None
        self._scene_transform = None
        self._start_point = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ALT:
            # Translate is broken when zoomed in.
            deltas = self._start_point - event.pos()

            transform = self.transform()
            delta_x = deltas.x() / transform.m11()
            delta_y = deltas.y() / transform.m22()

            self.setSceneRect(self.sceneRect().translated(delta_x, delta_y))
            self._start_point = event.pos()
        elif event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ALT:
            deltas = event.pos() - self._start_point
            scalar = deltas.x() * 0.005

            center = self._scene_rect.center()

            transform = QtGui.QTransform(self._scene_transform)
            transform.translate(center.x(), center.y())
            transform.scale(1 + scalar, 1 + scalar)
            transform.translate(-center.x(), -center.y())
            self.setTransform(transform)
        else:
            super(QGraphView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
```

Answer (score 2):

The scale transformation is always applied on the origin point of the matrix (the top left corner). This causes the scene rect to adapt inside the view.

To scale around a specific point, you need to first translate the matrix, then apply the scale, and finally restore the translation back:

```
            transform = QtGui.QTransform(self._scene_transform)
            center = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().rect().center())
            transform.translate(center.x(), center.y())
            transform.scale(1 + scalar, 1 + scalar)
            transform.translate(-center.x(), -center.y())

            self.setTransform(transform)
```

Notes:

- this only works as long as the transformation anchor is set to `NoAnchor`; for any other case, the computation might be more complex, especially if you want to translate around a specific point (and not the center of the view);
- if you plan to release your program for multiple platforms, you cannot use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier with mouse move events, because in other platforms (notably, Linux) it triggers window moving and resizing by default;

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense that it needs to be translated before being scaled. I'm still having some issues when it's zoomed in then translated. For some reason translate sticks when moving horizontally but moving vertically has no issues at all. I'm not sure if this is related to how it's scaling. The scene's rect does seem to be updating when translating but the items don't move or pop. Do you have any ideas why that is? I updated my post when the latest.

Comment: @GreenCell I'm deeply sorry, for some reason I didn't see your comment (or completely forgot about it), and casually found out about it while looking for another post of mine. The issue is caused by the way you're translating the scene which doesn't consider the available scroll area within the visible portion of the scene; you can understand it more if you leave the scroll bars active. If you've not found a solution for it, I'd suggest you to create a new question and I'll provide an answer for it. (Note: the issue already existed in your original code, and has nothing to do with my answer).